# Invertibility of the transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B = {**u**$_1$, **u**$_2$} and B' = {**u**$_1$ , **u**$_2$} two basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$

The book I'm studying says that the transition matrix is invertible because the column vectors that form it are linear independent.

\begin{equation}[\mathbf{v}]_{B} =  \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\
b & d\\
\end{array} \right) 
\left(\begin{array}{c} k_1 \\
k_2 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\
b & d\\
\end{array} \right) [\mathbf{v}]_{B'}\end{equation}

But these column vectors represent the coordinates of the vectors of the basis B' with respect to B. So I don't see how this can be a proof of the fact that the transition matrix is invertible. In B these vectors should not be linear independent because they are not part of this basis. So what Does prove that the matrix is invertible?

Comment: Linear independence is basis-independent :) Think of it this way: if the basis transformation matrix was singular, then there would be vectors in one basis that become the zero vector in the new basis!

Answer (score 1):

The transition matrix maps each vector from basis $B$ to one and only one vector from basis $B'$. Because it maps (in your case) two independent vectors to some other two independent vectors then we know it's invertible because it doesn't map any nonzero vector to a zero vector.